# Property does not exist on type 'never'.ts

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I'm adding Typescript to an existing Vue project. I've got this method:

```
const markImportant = (isImportant: boolean): void => {
  for (let email of store.selectedEmail) {
    if (isImportant) {
      email.important = isImportant;
      updateImportant(email);
  }
};
```

I'm using Pinia to store the `selectedEmail` object. I've got the following error message:

> Property 'important' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)

The value of `important` could be true or false.

How could I make this work?

Comment: If you don't use/like TS, you can always disable it.

Comment: How is `store.selectedEmail` defined?

Comment: I've got a JSON file that is loaded to the pinia store:
"read": true,
"important": false,
"from": "info@gmail.com",

Comment: It's an object and you iterate it as an array

Comment: The selectedEmail is an array of objects, that's why I can iterate through it.

Comment: This is not verifiable, we need to see what `store.selectedEmail` is. [mcve]